# How to programmatically create Google service account credentials?

Tags: google-oauth, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I have a desktop application which I want to create a new service account for each user of my application.

Is there any API for creating the `service account` users on the fly?

Scenario: For each user, I want to give `service account`, and give this service account the data that this user needs.

The point is that I want to give every user some specific data from Google Cloud, but I want the user to get it directly from Google. I cannot use the user account, because I am not sure he have google account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Google Identity and Access Management (IAM) API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/) to programatically create service accounts.

However, creating a service account for each of your application's users is expensive and not scalable. Perhaps your service can have a single service account and then the service can control which of the resources that the user may access.

Comment: You can follow this but you're going to run into difficulty if you want to create multiple accounts. The API won't let you specify the pseudo-email it gives to the account, so once you've created one service account for a project you're done - all subsequent requests will be rejected as the created service account would not be unique. You'll have to do it manually after that. See [docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/create)

Comment: You get the email address in the `email` field of the HTTP response

Comment: +1. When you are saying that the solution is not scalable (for every user) what are its limitations? I'd like to create a service account for each company using our service. I am assuming that would be fine?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Google Api that allows you to control projects on [Google Developer console](http://console.cloud.google.com).   The only thing that comes close is the [Google Cloud Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/) which is extremely limited in what it supports.  You cant use it to create a service account.

Answer:  The only way to create a new service account is to log in and do it though the Google Developers console.

Comment: Limit the number of service accounts you need by grouping the users by what they can see?   At any rate I think there is a limit to the number of credentials you can create in a project.  No I don't remember what it is just think I read about it some were ages ago.  I don't think google would let you make an unlimited number of service accounts at any rate how would you keep them strait if you wanted to remove someones access.

Comment: @DaImTo hi there - thanks for your answer above - a further question regarding it: would it make sense to programmatically create normal user accounts (if not service accounts) and then group users by what they can see? e.g. as suggested in this documentation: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users